# NavigationControl with Deck.gl

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl, deck.gl

I'm trying to build nft marketplace over mapbox, like ovr.ai to improve my react.js. I'm working on a fork, but I'm trying to add new features like navigation control, search place etc.

I have a problem with NavigationControl.

```
import DeckGL from "@deck.gl/react"
import ReactMapGL, { NavigationControl } from "react-map-gl"

return (
    <DeckGL
      style={{ position: "relative" }}
      height={HEIGHT}
      width={WIDTH}
      initialViewState={viewState}
      onViewStateChange={({ viewState }) => setViewState(viewState)}
      controller={true}
      layers={layers}
    >
      <ReactMapGL mapboxApiAccessToken={token}>
        <NavigationControl />
      </ReactMapGL>
    </DeckGL>
  )
```

Code generates navigation control but firstly; I can't click them because deckgl generates canvas over them. Even I remove canvas from inspect, zoom control seems not working.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-forest-iv6bi2?file=/src/Map/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As docs suggest [here](https://deck.gl/docs/whats-new#use-react-map-gl-components-with-deckgl), try adding the `react-map-gl` context provider to your `DeckGL` component

Answer (score 1):

Question are a bit old, but I just want to provide my findings or relevant answer for newer version of react-map-gl (v7) which already remove _MapContext.

Based on doc [here](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/map-provider) on MapProvider you need to add this wrap outside your Map component so that it will tells Deckgl for current map context and making navigation functional when using react-map-gl with deck.gl, like:

```
<DeckGL ... >
  <MapProvider>
    <Map ... >
```

Hope this will help someone stumble upon this like me for quite an hours.

Comment: I found that when you use MapProvider it will conflict with DeckGL layer, I did not notice it earlier until I have both layer on react-map-gl and DeckGL which can cause an issue, not sure on how to really make both works, unless make all layers in DeckGL and use only react-map-gl as static map